# Regex Pattern not stopping at first occurance

Tags: regex

I have the following regex expression.

`/<img.+src=['"](?P<src>.+?)['"].*>/i`

However When I run this on any string that has more than one image in it, it is returning the last image.  In fact it is returning the last src occurance regardless if it is an image or not.

And this is because it is selecting from `<img` to the last next linebreak and not stopping at the end `>` of the tag.

How can I change my regex to stop at the `>` of the `<img>` tag

Take a look at this example

https://regex101.com/r/QNQA72/2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @mparnisari: note that the accepted answer of this topic you linked is wrong *(this is the reason why I downvoted it)*, in particular for advanced regex engines. There's other topics that explain what are the alternatives to a direct string approach to parse HTML.

Comment: Try `<img.+?src=['"](?P<src>.+?)['"].*>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vufpzG/1)

Comment: @dawg that worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change `.*` to `.*?`, and `.+` to `.+?`

- `.*` is *greedy*, which matches as *much* as possible
- `.*?` is *reluctant*, which matches as *little* as possible

Same goes for the `+` versions.

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau just noticed you had another bug. See update.

Answer (score 0):

To answer exactly to your final question

> How can I change my regex to stop at the > of the  tag

you might merely turn `.+` into `[^>]+`:

```
/<img[^>]+src=['"](?P<src>.+?)['"].*>/i
```

But it's not a really good solution, because it will make the regex engine work hard.

A better solution is to work in two steps, first selecting entire `<img>` elements, then looking for `src` inside.
So if you want to show each of the `src`s in your `string`:

```
var images = string.match(/<img[^>]+>/ig);
for (img of images) {
    var match = img.match(/src=(["|'])([^'"]*)\1/);
    if (match) { // (avoid error when <img> doesn't contain src)
        console.log(match[2]);
    }
}
```

Note how we look for both `src="..."` or `src='...'`, capturing the opening quote by `(["|'])` then using backreference to ensure the closing quote is the same.